# how to access Flask REST API from other python app

Tags: python, flask

im tryin to understand how to access methods from rest api inside of my other python app.
im not able to find any video about that subject, so im tryin to figure out what url to type from my app to reach the methods i coded

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your flask app out of the box without specifying host or port, it will run at http://localhost:5000 by default.

Then, to get to the endpoints you have coded, you append the url that you specified in the flask route handler.

For example, if your simple flask app has a GET endpoint in a file called myapi.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get('/get_my_data')
def get_my_data():
    return jsonify(message: 'this is my data')
```

If you run it from the CLI like so:

```
>> export FLASK_APP=myapi.py
>> export FLASK_ENV=development
>> flask run
```

... then your path from your other app to your running flask development server would be: http://localhost:5000/get_my_data